# Mac Sonoma 14.4 Dotnet 8.0.203 SDK webapi https error

Tags: https, sdk, certificate, webapi, .net-8.0

I'm on a mac, Sonoma 14.4

I use the dotnet 8.0.203 SDK

When I create a webapi with `dotnet new webapi -n MyApp`, I get the weatherforecast for free.

When I run the server, and run `curl https://localhost:7067/weatherforecast` for the *first* time, I get the correct reponse, no problems there.

However, when I run the same curl command a *second* time, it also returns the correct response, but the server outputs this:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unhandled exception while processing 0HN2BATH5FO82.
      System.IO.IOException: The encryption operation failed, see inner exception.
       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (14): Bad address
```

I already refreshed my local certficates with `dotnet dev-certs -t`, so that is no solution.

When I create the exact same app with dotnet 7.0.202, there is no problem.

Anyone knows what is going on here? Should I file a bug report at Microsoft?

Thanks in advance